# How to handle mouse clicks in CMainFrame

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How can I detect in an "empty" CMainFrame mouse clicks? With empty I mean a MDI which has not yet any document/view.

I have tried to detect mouse clicks with:

```cpp
   afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);  
   BOOL CMainFrame::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDI main frame windows have an 'invisible' *client* window that occupies the client area of the main frame. This window is inaccessible using 'normal' class override techniques but, if that main frame window is derived from either `CMDIFrameWnd` or `CMDIFrameWndEx`, you can use its `m_hWndMDIClient` member (the `HWND` of that invisible window) to subclass it, by overriding its `WindowProc`.

I do this (actually, to draw in that client area) in an override of the main frame's `UpdateWindow` procedure, using a `bool` member variable (set to `false` on construction) to keep track of whether or not the subclassing has already been done.

Here's a possible solution (adapted from my own code) that will likely work for intercepting mouse clicks. (I tested it and did actually get the `Beep()` diagnostic on mouse clicks!)

```cpp
// Local function pointer to store the 'original' (default) window procedure...
LRESULT (CALLBACK *DefCliPrc)(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = nullptr;

// Static definition of our override procedure...
static LRESULT CALLBACK ClientProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT answer = DefCliPrc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // First, call default proc.
    if (uMsg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        Beep(1000,1000); // Make a sound to show that it's working!
        // <Insert your handling code here>
    }
    //...
    // Intercept/handle other messages, as required ...
    //...
    return answer;
}

// Override of the UpdateWindow function, to enact the subclassing...
void MyMainFrame::UpdateWindow(void)
{
    if (!funchange) { // Only do the sub-classing ONCE ...
        DefCliPrc = (WNDPROC)(intptr_t)(::GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWndMDIClient, GWLP_WNDPROC));
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWndMDIClient, GWLP_WNDPROC, (intptr_t)(ClientProc));
        funchange = true; // Set this 'flag' to prevent repetition!
    }
    CMDIFrameWnd::UpdateWindow(); // Should always call base class
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. m_hWndMDIClient pointed me to the right direction. With this Info I could handle it finally in PreTranslateMsg() too.  if (pMsg->hwnd == m_hWndMDIClient) { if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) .. }